# WPF ItemsControl is not rendering UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

Here is the UI code to loop string array:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding sideMenuCollection}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                <TextBlock Text="&#xf0e4;" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" FontSize="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="26" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="smb_dashboard" MouseDown="smb_dashboard_MouseDown"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public List<string> sideMenuCollection = new List<string> {
            "Dashboard", 
            "Customers",
            "Items", 
            "Reports"
        };
```

No idea what's going wrong here ?

It should be creating sidemenus in red area.

[image]

Comment: How do you set up the datacontext of that window ?

Comment: I am beginner. I am not getting your question ?

Comment: Hey @AshishGehlot wait. I think I have found a solution for you. Please let me check first. :)

Comment: @AshishGehlot Please check the code. It is working in both WPF and Silverligh.Best Wishes. :)

Comment: See the edited answer for how to fix your *actual* problem, i.e. the non-working binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make

```
ItemsSource="{Binding sideMenuCollection}"
```

work, `sideMenuCollection` must be a property, not a field, and the `DataContext` of the Window should be set to the Window instance, which owns the property:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> sideMenuCollection { get; } = new List<string>
    {
        "Dashboard",
        "Customers",
        "Items",
        "Reports"
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the answer you are expecting?

Comment: Yes @Linker, I was following MVVM tutorial and have knowledge of window forms so Mixed logics.

Comment: great. go ahead.